# Mysql query using UNION

Tags: mysql, union

```
$sql = "SELECT `employee`.`employee_id`, `employee`.`employee_pre_code`, `employee`.`employee_code`, `employee`.`employee_name`, `employee`.`active`, `designation`.`designation_name`, `employeetype`.`employee_type_name`, `supervisor`.`supervisor_id`, `incharge`.`incharge_id`, `subsection`.`subsection_id`, `section`.`section_id`, `floor`.`floor_id`, `unit`.`unit_id`, `attendance_summery`.`present_days`,`attendance_summery`.`working_days` 
          FROM `employee` LEFT JOIN `designation` ON `employee`.`designation_id`=`designation`.`designation_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `employeetype` ON `employee`.`employee_type_id` = `employeetype`.`employee_type_id`
          LEFT JOIN `supervisor` ON `supervisor`.`supervisor_id` = `employee`.`supervisor_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `incharge` ON `incharge`.`incharge_id` = `supervisor`.`incharge_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `subsection` ON `subsection`.`subsection_id` = `incharge`.`subsection_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `section` ON `section`.`section_id` = `subsection`.`section_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `floor` ON `floor`.`floor_id` = `section`.`floor_id` 
          LEFT JOIN `unit` ON `unit`.`unit_id` = `floor`.`floor_id`    
          WHERE `employee`.`unit_id` = '1' AND `employee`.`active` = 1 
UNION
        SELECT `employee`.`employee_id`, `employee`.`employee_pre_code`, `employee`.`employee_code`, `employee`.`employee_name`, `employee`.`active`, `designation`.`designation_name`, `employeetype`.`employee_type_name`, `supervisor`.`supervisor_id`, `incharge`.`incharge_id`, `subsection`.`subsection_id`, `section`.`section_id`, `floor`.`floor_id`, `unit`.`unit_id`, `attendance_summery`.`present_days`,`attendance_summery`.`working_days` FROM `employee` 
          LEFT JOIN `attendance_summery` ON `attendance_summery`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`employee_id` 
          WHERE `attendance_summery`.`payment_period_id` = 36 
          ORDER BY `employee`.`employee_name` ASC";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
```

A Database **Error Occurred**

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'attendance_summery.present_days' in 'field list'

But the column `'attendance_summery.present_days'` exists.

I failed to find the problem with the query.

Can any one help.

Comment: Its probably a typing mistake, double check the spellings of the table and field name

Answer (score 1):

**attendance_summery** table is not selected in the first query of the union.

You will have to add ;

```
LEFT JOIN `attendance_summery` ON `attendance_summery`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`employee_id
```

to the first select of your sql. You need to test each field and add them.

Comment: 'present_days' field only exists in attendance_summery table.thanks.

Comment: Can you please help rewriting.

Comment: joined but another message come Unknown column 'designation.designation_name' in 'field list'

Comment: Have to tested your individual queries?

Comment: I have tested the query without union and the where clause of the second select, then it works. Can you give me suggession how can I add the where clause of the 2nd clause anyway without union joining the working days of employees where payment_period_id is 36

Answer (score 1):

don't you think, `attendance_summery` table should **not** be a part of `FROM` clause of first query while it is part of `select list`? I cant see `attendance_summery` table in `FROM CALUSE` which is miss!!

Comment: I need to join a field from attendance_summery to employee table data.

Comment: rephrase it above.. what i meant is.. i can't see the attendance_summery table in first query while it is part of select list of first query.. which means.. what you are missing it is to add attendance_summery in FROM List and it should resolve it.

Comment: So what would be the solution. can you please rewrite.

Comment: Join employee with attendance_summery in first query as you did in 2nd query 

FROM `employee` 
          LEFT JOIN `attendance_summery` ON `attendance_summery`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`employee_id`

Comment: joined but another message come Unknown column 'designation.designation_name' in 'field list

Comment: check if designation table is present in FROM list? if not join it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90145/discussion-between-hafsul-maru-and-nitin-tripathi).

Comment: Atlast!! Great News!!

Answer (score 0):

My main issue was to use multiple conditions in JOINing the tables. At last added two conditions when joining `attendance_summery` table with AND keyword which joins the rows that only matches `$paymentPeriodId` variable. That fulfilled what I wanted. Again thanks for `Jerome Anthony` and `Nitin Tripathi`. My updated query is as:

```
$sql = "SELECT `employee`.`employee_id`, `employee`.`employee_pre_code`, `employee`.`employee_code`, `employee`.`employee_name`, `employee`.`active`, `designation`.`designation_name`, `employeetype`.`employee_type_name`, `supervisor`.`supervisor_id`, `incharge`.`incharge_id`, `subsection`.`subsection_id`, `section`.`section_id`, `floor`.`floor_id`, `unit`.`unit_id`, `attendance_summery`.`present_days`, `attendance_summery`.`working_days` "
      . "FROM `employee` "
      . "LEFT JOIN `designation` ON `employee`.`designation_id`=`designation`.`designation_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `employeetype` ON `employee`.`employee_type_id` = `employeetype`.`employee_type_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `supervisor` ON `supervisor`.`supervisor_id` = `employee`.`supervisor_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `incharge` ON `incharge`.`incharge_id` = `supervisor`.`incharge_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `subsection` ON `subsection`.`subsection_id` = `incharge`.`subsection_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `section` ON `section`.`section_id` = `subsection`.`section_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `floor` ON `floor`.`floor_id` = `section`.`floor_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `unit` ON `unit`.`unit_id` = `floor`.`floor_id`"
      . "LEFT JOIN `attendance_summery` ON (`attendance_summery`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`employee_id` AND `attendance_summery`.`payment_period_id` = $paymentPeriodId )"
      . "WHERE `employee`.`unit_id` = '1' AND `employee`.`active` = '1' "
      . "ORDER BY `employee`.`employee_name` ASC"; 

      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      return $query->result_array();
```